# How i can make loading controls in Binding without blocking UI?

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, binding

i have this situation:

i want to load a collection in my ViewModel in the MainWindow i have a big data so when i enter to the slide of people collection it should wait to finish loading then i can see the full list, i have the follwing:

- in the xaml code i have:

  ```
  <ListView ..... 
  ItemsSource{Binding PeopleList, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}
  ... />
  ```
- and in the viewmode i have:

  ```
  // ...
  private ObservableCollection<Person> _People;
  public ObservableCollection<Person> People
  { get{return _People;} set{ _People = value; RaisePropertyChange("People");}}
  // ...
  ```

and i want to load all the people list one by one after load the first one completely start loading the second ... etc without blocking the mainwindow i want my window looks like:

[image: UI Example]

i tired to do it my self but i fail. thanks before.

Comment: In paragraph one you finish loading then in paragraph two you want to load one by one.  What problem are you tying to solve?

Comment: @Blam in the first one i meant loading in the logic, and in the second i meant the loading on the UI.

Comment: Once you have the data then why do you want to paint the UI a person at a time.  That should be very very fast.  With virtualization is only paint what is on the items in view.  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @Blam i tired the visualization but also it is failed. cause i have a big data, in every loading time when i visit the persons list, and the items template is very big also.

Comment: Post your full code and XAML, and a `clear`, specific explanation of your current problem.

Comment: Virtualization not visualization.  Paint one control at a time is not the correct way to address a slow rendering.

Answer (score 2):

There exist ways for to modify view from another thread, using the SynchronizationContext.

Please see this example:

```
        private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            var sync = SynchronizationContext.Current;
            BackgroundWorker w = new BackgroundWorker();
            w.DoWork+=(_, __)=>
                {
                    //sync.Post(p => { button.Content = "Working"; }, null);
                    int j = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
                    {
                        j++;
                        sync.Post(p => { button.Content = j.ToString(); }, null);
                        Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    }
                    sync.Post(p => { button.Background = Brushes.Aqua; button.Content = "Some Content"; }, null);
                };
            w.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

And this is the view:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication2.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Button x:Name="button" Content="Some Content" Click="Button_Click"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This code, updates several times the view (a button in this case). I think this solve your initial question.

**----EDIT----**

This is a better way of using this idea: I propose to create a method like this in a base view model:

```
    public void LockAndDoInBackground(Action action, string text, Action beforeVisualAction = null, Action afterVisualAction = null)
    {
        if (IsBusy)
            return;
        var currentSyncContext = SynchronizationContext.Current;
        ActiveThread = new Thread((_) =>
        {                
            currentSyncContext.Send(t =>
            {
                IsBusy = true;
                BusyText = string.IsNullOrEmpty(text) ? "Wait please..." : text;
                if (beforeVisualAction != null)
                    beforeVisualAction();
            }, null);
            action();
            currentSyncContext.Send(t =>
            {
                IsBusy = false;
                BusyText = "";
                if (afterVisualAction != null)
                    afterVisualAction();
            }, null);
        });
        ActiveThread.Start();
    }
```

In this way any child view model can use this for excecuting big amount of data processing, and the UI does not get freeze. `IsBusy` and `BusyText` are the view models variables wich are bound to the View Wait Message and the Visibility of a Wait Element.
This is an example of use in a child view model's command:

```
  private RelayCommand _SomeCommand;
  public RelayCommand SomeCommand
    {
        get { return _SomeCommand ?? (_SomeCommand = new RelayCommand(ExecuteSomeCommand, CanExecuteSomeCommand)); }
    }

    private void ExecuteSomeCommand()
    {
        Action t = ()=> 
        {
            //some action
        };

        LockAndDoInBackground(t, "Generating Information...");
    }

    private bool CanExecuteSomeCommand()
    {
        return SelectedItem != null;
    }
```

Hope this will become a more clear example.

Comment: Your solution does not conform to any of the established good practices and patterns in WPF. You should be using DataBinding and a proper ViewModel instead of having your code coupled to the UI like this.

Comment: HighCore: It is just a simple example, the idea is to post the actions (in the sync contest) that change the view (for instace: change the properties values that are bound to the view items).

Comment: `It is just a simple example` - your simple example does not conform to any of the established good practices and patterns in WPF. You should be using DataBinding and a proper ViewModel instead of having your code coupled to the UI like this.

Comment: The way this idea id used is programmer responsabillity.

Comment: -Or- you can delete this answer which encourages all sorts of horribly bad practices and post a proper answer which conforms to the WPF mentality rather than an archaic winforms approach.

Comment: +1 for a properly designed approach and a comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

The way I would do it:

- add `IsLoading` flag to item
- the `DataTemplate` for the item should check for that flag, and for
  `IsLoading=true` it should show some marquee progress, otherwise the
  real data
- add empty item object to ObservableCollection with `IsLoading = TRUE`,
  then start retrieving item data on another thread
- after retrieving item data, in the UI thread set the `IsLoading = FALSE`
- the item should implement 'INotifyPropertyChanged' and all visible
  properties should send PropertyChanged event

Comment: thanks for ur answer please could u see this [problem after do some thing like what u said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23228046/why-my-listview-re-render-all-items-at-every-itemscollection-changing)

Answer (score 0):

You have two options to achieve your desired scenario:

- Use **BackgroundWorker** and implement it. The `ProgressChanged` will be appropriate if you want to use it with a progress. The `DoWork` will be your heavy loading of your data. The `CompletedEvent` is your finish up on that task.
- Use **TPL**, you can start using it right away with `Task.Factory.StartNew()` and give the action as 
  your data load. And one one it's constructor you can pass in `TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext()` so it can marshall it to the `UI Dispatcher`.
- Sample for [Task Parallel Library](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/221969/WPF-dont-block-your-UI)
- Sample for [BackgroundWorker](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/99143/BackgroundWorker-Class-Sample-for-Beginners)