# Why my ListView re-load all items at every itemsCollection changing?

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, user-interface

Hi guys i have this situation:

- i have a ListView with ItemTemplate and VirtualizingPanel as itemsPanel, my list view bond to an ObservableCollection as follow:

  ```
  //...
  <ListView x:Name="MyListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Products, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource    ItemContainerStyle}">    <ListView.ItemsPanel>
  <ItemsPanelTemplate>
  <VirtulizingPanel IsItemsHost="True" />
  </ItemsPanelTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemsPanel>
  </ListView>
  //...
  ```
- and in the MainViewModel i have this code to fill the collection:

  ```
      backworker.DoWork += (s, e) =>
          {
              for (int i = 0; i < 800; i++ )
              {
                  if (!backworker.CancellationPending)
                  {
                      DispatcherHelper.UIDispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(() =>
                      {
                          this.Products.Add(new Product()
                          {

                              ID = i,
                              Name = string.Format("Product {0}", i),
                              Category = new Category() { Name = "Standard Category" },
                              SalePrice = i*50, IsActive = true

                          });
                      }));
                  }
                  else
                  {
                      break;
                  }

                  System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(500);
              }
  ```

  - my item style:

    ```
    <Style x:Key="ItemContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}" BasedOn=" {StaticResource MetroListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="Bd" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="5" Padding="10" Width="350" Height="55" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" ToolTip="{Binding Name}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="10*" MaxWidth="150" />
                                    <ColumnDefinition />
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="5*" MaxWidth="150" />
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Rectangle x:Name="PART_Background" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" Fill="Silver" Opacity=".7" Margin="-10" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_Icon"
                                           Margin="2,2,10,2"
                                           Height="25"
                                           TextAlignment="Center"
                                           helpers:ProductHelper.isQuantityFollowing="True"
                                           Text="{StaticResource Product}"
                                           FontFamily="minigcrm"
                                           FontSize="24" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_Name"
                                           Text="{Binding Name}"
                                           TextTrimming="CharacterEllipsis"
                                           Foreground="Black" Grid.Column="1"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI"
                                           FontSize="17"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
                                <TextBlock x:Name="PART_Count"
                                           Text="{Binding PurchasePrice, StringFormat={StaticResource (PriceDZDString)}}"
                                           Foreground="#555"
                                           Grid.Column="3"
                                           FontFamily="Segoe UI Light"
                                           FontSize="15"
                                           VerticalAlignment="Center" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Right"/>
                                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.ColumnSpan="4" VerticalAlignment="Top" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Margin="-9">
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_MoveToTrashOrRestor"
                                            Style="{StaticResource FlatAndScaleButtonStyle}"
                                            ToolTip="{StaticResource MoveToTrashString}"
                                            Width="15"
                                            Height="15"
                                            Margin="2"
                                            Command="{Binding Main.ChangeProductStatusCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                            Content="{StaticResource Remove}"
                                            FontFamily="minigcrm"
                                            FontSize="12"
                                            Foreground="#555"
                                            Cursor="Hand" />
                                    <Button x:Name="PART_Delete"
                                            Style="{StaticResource FlatAndScaleButtonStyle}"
                                            ToolTip="{StaticResource DeleteString}"
                                            Width="15"
                                            Height="15"
                                            Margin="2"
                                            Command="{Binding Main.DeleteProductCommand, Source={StaticResource Locator}}"
                                            CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                                            Content="{StaticResource Close}"
                                            FontFamily="minigcrm"
                                            FontSize="15"
                                            Foreground="#555"
                                            Cursor="Hand" 
                                            Visibility="{Binding IsActive, Converter={StaticResource InvertBooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsSelected" Value="true">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Name" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Count" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Icon" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_MoveToTrashOrRestor" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Delete" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" Color="LightGray" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Name" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Count" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Icon" Property="Foreground" Value="White" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_MoveToTrashOrRestor" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Delete" Property="Foreground" Value="WhiteSmoke" />
                                <Setter Property="Effect">
                                    <Setter.Value>
                                        <DropShadowEffect Direction="0" ShadowDepth="0" BlurRadius="10" Color="LightGray" />
                                    </Setter.Value>
                                </Setter>
                            </Trigger>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_Background" Property="Fill" Value="Orange"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_MoveToTrashOrRestor" Property="Content" Value="{StaticResource Restore}"/>
                                <Setter TargetName="PART_MoveToTrashOrRestor" Property="ToolTip" Value="{StaticResource RestoreString}"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <!--<DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />  
                    <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                </DataTrigger>-->
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsActive, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Orange" />
                </DataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Active, ElementName=THIS, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="True"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Inactive, ElementName=THIS, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding IsActive, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Value="False"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                        <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Setters>
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    ```

the problem that i have is in each change in the Products Collection(when i add new item) the ListView In the UI re-Load all items  that causes a slow rendering specially when the items count greater then 50 item, pleas what is the problem? thanks in advance.

Comment: How you come to conclusion that all items are rendering again?

Comment: What is purpose of this design?   Of the 800 most are not even going to be in view?

Comment: @RohitVats when i run my project i see the items being added to the ListView one by one, but in each time the list view reload all items again!!? cause i made a behavior in itemStyle on opacity by using storyboard to increase the opacity when item loaded. so i saw all items doing this behavior every time when add new item.

Comment: Can you show us what you are using for ItemContainerStyle?

Comment: @FodderZone i use the style that i added to the question cause the style so long.

Comment: Why do you have a call to Sleep in that loop?

Comment: @FodderZone: if i didn't the UI thread will blocked cause i call the dispacherUI and it block the UI for each item, the loop is very quickly so i will not have chance to click an item or looking to the loading on the UI.

Comment: The reason your UI is running slow is because of that sleep call. In almost every case related to UIs you should never use sleep.